# In UI Testing, can I use private API?

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm using some private API to access source code from UI Testing.
Will my code or resource in UI Testing submitted together with source code to Apple to review ?

Answer (score 2):

To me, this puts Apple's native UI Testing package at a huge disadvantage. This isn't a huge problem for iOS since there are so many 3rd party packages that allow you to test UI on top of the Unit Test package and eschew the UI package all together. This is less the case if you are working on tvOS or macOS projects that don't quite have the same support. tvOS is currently broken in a lot of ways for UI Testing.

In the end, to REALLY test your application with UI Tests, you will have to do a lot more work to make things work natively. Most answers will tell you to use `-launchEnvironment` or `-launchArguments` to pass in whatever data your app needs to run the UI Test. I can tell you this does work, however it fails to let you know just how much extra work is needed to make this work effectively. Any mocking or stubbing of data for a UI Test needs to be using production code. As in, you have to include your logic for launch args and environment variables and change your app at runtime. Not exactly a great approach if you ask me, but can be done.

In the end, I ended up sacrificing a small bit of production code to guarantee I can run UI Tests and protect the larger bit of the app. I had built my own networking library to make the calls for data I needed, so it allowed me to program a "test" path for network requests that allowed me to return data I needed for the API calls. Essentially a custom filename for a user and hash of url and parameters that let my networking library return the specific payload for that API. Once it was working, it worked great. I still feel a little dirty doing it, but it does work.

No amount of trial and error allowed me to mock or stub data in a UI Test. In the end, it came down to programming the test data into the app and using launch args. Fingers crossed WWDC 17 will have better news.

Comment: yes, I'm using stubbing and mocking to access to the app when running. There're so many bugs and limitations of UI Test now. But this is the best tool for automation testing right now and sure it'll better soon.

Comment: I'd love to see how you are able to mock and stub methods using Apple's UI Tests. Everything I've seen and read indicates that this is not possible without baking some of the mocking into the app itself, which is what I've had to do to make it work for my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

No they won´t be visible.

> @testable provides access only for “internal” functions; “private”
>   declarations are not visible outside of their file even when using
>   @testable.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word. I mean "private API" not "private method"

Comment: Yes you can, but if you publish you app with private API´s it will be rejected from Apple.

Comment: I only use those in UI Testing, not in source code of app. So the question is Will my code or resource in UI Testing submitted together with source code of the app to Apple to review ?

Comment: No you will only publish the targets you choose.